# Newline in Huffman Tree

Tags: c++, class, huffman-code

My Huffman tree is suppose to print

CR for displaying character '\n'
LF for displaying character '\r'

but it just prints a blank space.

Here's my code so far:

```
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>

#define MAX_TREE_HT 2048

using namespace std;

// map characters to value
map<char, string> codes;

// store frequences
map<char, int> freq;

// Create tree.
struct HuffmanTree {
    char data;                 // One of the input characters
    int freq;                  // Frequency of the character
    HuffmanTree *left, *right; // Left and right child

    HuffmanTree(char data, int freq) {
        left = right = NULL;
        this->data = data;
        this->freq = freq;
    }
};

// Compare Function
struct compare {
    bool operator()(HuffmanTree* l, HuffmanTree* r) { return (l->freq > r->freq); }
};

void printCodes(struct HuffmanTree* root, string str) {
    if(!root) return;
    if(root->data != '$') cout << root->data << ": " << str << "\n";
    printCodes(root->left, str + "0");
    printCodes(root->right, str + "1");
}

void storeCodes(struct HuffmanTree* root, string str) {
    if(root == NULL) return;
    if(root->data != '$') codes[root->data] = str;
    storeCodes(root->left, str + "0");
    storeCodes(root->right, str + "1");
}

// Use vector and queue
//
priority_queue<HuffmanTree*, vector<HuffmanTree*>, compare> minHeap;

// build tree and store codes
void HuffmanCodes(int size) {
    struct HuffmanTree *left, *right, *top;
    for(map<char, int>::iterator v = freq.begin(); v != freq.end(); v++)
        minHeap.push(new HuffmanTree(v->first, v->second));
    while(minHeap.size() != 1) {
        left = minHeap.top();
        minHeap.pop();
        right = minHeap.top();
        minHeap.pop();
        top = new HuffmanTree('$', left->freq + right->freq);
        top->left = left;
        top->right = right;
        minHeap.push(top);
    }
    storeCodes(minHeap.top(), "");
}

// map frequencies
void calcFreq(string str, int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++) freq[str[i]]++;
}

int main() {
    ifstream t("file.txt");
    string str((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(t)),
               std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());

    string encodedString;
    calcFreq(str, str.length());
    HuffmanCodes(str.length());
    for(auto v = codes.begin(); v != codes.end(); v++)
        cout << "{key: " << v->first << ' ' << v->second << "}" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Here's the example input file "file.txt":

```
This is a test line. 
This is a test line. 
This is a test line.
```

Here's the output:

```
{key:
 10100}
{key:   111}
{key: T 10101}
{key: a 01101}
{key: e 001}
{key: f 01100}
{key: h 0100}
{key: i 110}
{key: l 1011}
{key: n 0111}
{key: s 100}
{key: t 000}
{key: w 0101}
```

This is a basic Huffman tree without anything fancy.  I just need to map the frequencies of the newlines and carriage returns.  I am using a g++ compile in Ubuntu running on Windows 10.

Comment: Where is your attempt to match control characters to names?

Comment: Okay, the mapping is only doing chars which does not include control characters?

Comment: Right now all the characters are being correctly added in the tree (well, I haven't verified whether the ordering is correct) but when you print the tree in `main()`, you just write the character itself to `cout`, not its name.

Comment: Okay, so since those characters are not printable, I need to include the text in the cout to print <CR> and \N for newline?

Comment: Yes, the computer does only what you tell it.  If you write a newline character to `cout` you get an actual newline.  The escape sequences `'\n'` and `'\r'` would be pretty useless if they printed out like their source code instead of creating actual control characters.

Comment: For the record: CR -> Carriage Return -> `'\r'`; LF -> Line Feed -> `'\n'`. To remember this easy: `'\r'` like carriage **R**eturn, `'\n'` like **N**ew line.

Comment: Okay, what about sorting by frequency?  I have it sorted by characters.